# How delete model with linked file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I see by default carrierwave does not delete files linked to model.
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carrierwave should remove the files from S3 automatically for you. I just tested this out on a Rails 3.1 app.

Comment: It looks like Carrierwave removed the file but doesn't remove empty directories.  I should have stuck with paperclip.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
@image.destroy
```

not

```
@image.delete
```

Also use refresh button on aws s3 panel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with carrierwave, but in general, hooking into the `after_destroy` is likely what you want.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :delete_linked_file

  def delete_linked_file
    # Delete the linked file here
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like carrierwave should handle it by itself. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/carrierwave/KUyXuQdYcFw. But I have the same problem too =((

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You can do it like this

```
def delete_image_folder
    FileUtils.remove_dir(File.join(Rails.root, File.join( 'public' , file_name.store_dir)), :force => true)  
end
```

but just remember that if you changed the Carrierwave configuration root, you should take it into account (default is public so this code will work)